# stylelint throws at-rule-* errors when parsing LESS variables

Tags: webpack, postcss, stylelint, postcss-loader, less-loader

I'm using `stylelint`as a `postcss` plugin in my webpack config. Further up the chain (so being executed after the postcss-loader), I'm also using `less-loader`. All dependencies are used in their most current versions.

**webpack.config.js**

```
...
'less-loader',
{
    loader: 'postcss-loader',
    options: {
        plugins: [
            require('stylelint')({
                "extends": "stylelint-config-standard"
            })
        ]
    }
}
...
```

Everything works fine, the linting throws meaningful errors if there are any. However, since I added a less variable in camelCase notation, I get `at-rule-*` related errors as well:

```
(1:1) Expected "fadeAnimDuration:" to be "fadeanimduration:" (at-rule-name-case)
...
(1:1) Unexpected unknown at-rule "@fadeAnimDuration:" (at-rule-no-unknown)
```

It seems that this was once a known issue but should have been fixed with 9.8.0 according to the changelog: https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#980

- Fixed: at-rule-* false positives for Less variables and mixins (#3767).

These are the lines in my `.less` file being linted:

```
@fadeAnimDuration: 1480ms;
...
some selector {
    transition: background-color @fadeAnimDuration, color @fadeAnimDuration;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

I can get rid of the camel case error changing the variable to `@fade-anim-duration`, but the second error still remains:

```
(1:1) Unexpected unknown at-rule "@fade-anim-duration:" (at-rule-no-unknown)
```

I don't want to have to disable those rules completely just to be able to use LESS variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using stylelint as a PostCSS plugin, I believe you'll need to manually set the postcss-loader [syntax configuration](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader#syntax) to [postcss-less](https://github.com/shellscape/postcss-less).

Alternatively, and I recommend this approach, you can use [stylelint-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/stylelint-webpack-plugin) and take advantage of the syntax switching built into stylelint.

Comment: Unfortunately, setting `syntax: 'postcss-less'` in the loader options didn't change anything. I'll give the stylelint webpack plugin a try!

Comment: Turns out I was just stupid and added the parameter in the wronge place of my webpack config (I have postcss-loader in there twice in order to execute autoprefixer and cssnano after less-loader and the linting before it. Added it to the first instance in the chain and it works like a charm, thanks!